# Стоимость вариативного товара

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Где корзина получает стоимость вариативного товара, с последующим перемножением на количество и выдачей **ИТОГ** и **ПОДИТОГ**?
Проблема в том что нужно отправить стоимость товара из произвольного поля в корзину.

Для простого товара все получилось.
В файле **abstract-wc-product.php** добавил следующую функцию:

```
    public function get_rrp_price( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_meta( $key = 'rrp_price', $context = 'view' );
}
```

Где `rrp_price` — название произвольного поля с новой ценой.
Затем в шаблоне **class-wc-cart.php**, а именно в следующих функциях:

```
public function calculate_totals(
public function get_product_subtotal(
```

Заменил `$product->get_price()` на `$product->get_rrp_price()` и для простого товара все заработало!

Но при добавлении вариативного товара корзина выдает `НУЛЬ`.
Не могу понять в каком месте это можно исправить, догадываюсь что в **class-wc-product-variable.php**, но если так, то где и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лезть в код WooCommerce - последнее дело. При обновлении все ваши правки слетят. WordPress и WooCommerce широко поддерживают концепцию хуков (через действия и фильтры). Для фильтрации цены простого товара используйте фильтр `woocommerce_get_price`

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_price( $price, $_this ) {
    // Присвойте $price значение
    return $price;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 2 );
```

а для вариативного - `filter_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price`

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price( $price, $_this) {
    if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
        $data            = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $parent_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $product_id      = 417;
        $attribute_name  = 'pa_color';
        $attribute_value = 'red';
        if ( $product_id === $parent_id ) {
            if ( $attribute_value === $_this->attributes[ $attribute_name ] ) {
                $variation_price = $data->price + 40;
                $price           = $variation_price;
            }
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'filter_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 10, 2);
```

В примере надо заменить `417`, `pa_color`, `red` на значения, относящиеся к товару и вариации.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67717/discussion-on-answer-by-kagg-design---).

Comment: как только заношу цену из произвольного поля в **$price** , в корзину заносится НОЛЬ, 
а если добавить еще одно условие (if), то в корзину - старая цена, 
если не указывать **$product_id**, тоже старая цена в корзину,
грешу на произвольное поле, так как при выводе на экран там **string(0)**, но в админке то числа

Comment: кстати с простым товаром это тоже не работает, в корзину - старая цена, хотя на экран и **var_dump** показывают новую, даже если использовать этот хук **'woocommerce_product_get_price'**

Comment: Вопрос был про вариативный, с ним работает - 200%, я тестировал. А про простой можно задать новый вопрос)

Comment: составил вопрос отражающий всю суть проблемы, мб я изначально сделал что то не так

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736700/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F

Comment: я вижу, отвечу...