# Отправить свою цену в корзину из произвольного поля

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вопрос заключается в следующем.
Настряпал код который перемножает цену товара на определенный курс, по заданному признаку и записывает новую цену в произвольное поле **'rrp_price'**:

```
    function my_woocommerce_get_price($price, $_product) {

$rooms2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rooms2', true );
$kurs = 1;
$kurs2 = 10;
$kurs3 = 100;

if ($rooms2 == 1) {

    $new_price = $price * $kurs2;

    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "rrp_price", $new_price );


return $new_price;

} elseif ($rooms2 == 2) {

    $new_price = $price * $kurs3;

    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "rrp_price", $price );


return $new_price;


} else {

    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "rrp_price",  $price ); // в последствии произвольное поле используется для сортировки по возрастанию/убыванию

}

return $price;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100,2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100,2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100,2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100,2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_variation_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100,2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_variation_regular_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100, 2);
add_filter( 'filter_woocommerce_variation_prices', 'my_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 3 );
```

Где **rooms2** - это еще одно произвольное поле куда заносится признак **(1,2,3 и т.д)**
Все работает как для простого так и для вариативного товара (за исключекнием того что в вариациях, в произвольных полях **'rrp_price'** (в админке) показана  новая цена только одной вариации, хотя на сайте у каждой своя).
Вопрос стоит в том чтобы отправить цену из произвольного поля в корзину (так как там отображается старая)?

Comment: Я не вижу тут обработки вариаций. Есть два поля: `rrp_price` - цена и `room2` - признак. Где хранятся цены вариаций?

Comment: в `'rrp_price'` - у каждой вариации он есть, но во всех одна цена (в админке), на самом сайте же цены перемножаются и выводятся как надо, при регистрации произвольного поля добавил следующие хуки:
`add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wc_rrp_product_field' );
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'wc_rrp_product_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes_js', 'wc_rrp_product_field'  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'wc_rrp_product_field' , 10, 1 );`

Comment: я спрашиваю о том, как в опциях хранится цена вариаций, чтобы сделать свой код

Comment: так, туплю, если вы за админку ( в чем я сомневаюсь) то там есть `variable_regular_price[]` и в некотороых `variable_sale_price[]`

Comment: как, используя, get_option() получить цену вариации вашего товара? или она тоже зависит от room2 - и все? Иными словами, какие произвольные поля есть у вариативного товара? Тоже всего два?

Comment: два поля да, только `rooms2` - одно, а `rrp_price` -  у каждой вариации

Comment: ну начинается)) каким кодом вы извлекаете/записываете rrp_price каждой вариации? где он в вопросе? почему сразу его в вопросе нет? ну нельзя же так, в самом деле - вы просто убиваете мое время на расследование.

Comment: покажите мне картинку админки вариативного товара, типа такой: http://take.ms/xmmW8

Comment: прошу прощения, просто кода у меня то и нет, записываю при помощи update_post_meta, https://ibb.co/bDB0Lm

Comment: "rooms" к делу не относится, только "rooms2", опыта у меня мизер, поэтому заранее извиняюсь за рофлы

Comment: ну и записываете вы своим кодом только одно поле rrp2 для вариативного товара, независимо от кол-ва вариаций. Я дал ответ, который делает то же самое (одно поле), только правильно

Comment: получается так да, но на сайте для каждой вариации - цена своя, поэтому я имел глупость оставить этот вопрос, так как не узнал как сделать это для каждой

Comment: да у меня тоже для каждой вариации цена своя

Comment: http://test.kagg.eu/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B/quia-qui-atque-quia-magnam/?attribute_pa_color=red сейчас только поправлю вывод диапазона цен и добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такой код в functions.php вашей темы. Ваш код уберите - все эти хуки лишние.

```
function get_rrp_price( $price, $product_id ) {
    $rooms2 = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rooms2', true );
    if ( '' === $rooms2) {
        $rooms2 = 1; // значение по умолчанию, если нет мета-поля
    }

    $kurs = 1;
    $kurs2 = 10;
    $kurs3 = 100;

    // Впоследствии произвольное поле rrp_price используется для сортировки по возрастанию/убыванию
    switch ( $rooms2 ) {
        case 1:
            $rrp_price = $price * $kurs2;
            break;
        case 2:
            $rrp_price = $price * $kurs3;
            break;
        default:
            $rrp_price = $price * $kurs;
            break;
    }

    return $rrp_price;
}

function filter_woocommerce_get_price( $price, $_this ) {
    $product_id = $_this->id;
    $rrp_price = get_rrp_price( $price, $product_id );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'rrp_price', $rrp_price );

    return $rrp_price;
}

function filter_736700_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price( $price, $_this) {
    if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
        $data            = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $variation_price = $data->price;
        $product_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $variation_rrp_price = get_rrp_price( $variation_price, $product_id );
        $price = $variation_rrp_price;
    }

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'filter_736700_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 10, 2);

function filter_736700_woocommerce_variation_prices( $prices_array, $product, $include_taxes ) {
    // Смените значения в $prices_array

    $product_id = $product->id;

    foreach ( $prices_array['price'] as $key => $price ) {
        $prices_array['price'][ $key ] = get_rrp_price( $price, $product_id );
    }

    foreach ( $prices_array['regular_price'] as $key => $price ) {
        $prices_array['price'][ $key ] = get_rrp_price( $price, $product_id );
    }

    foreach ( $prices_array['sale_price'] as $key => $price ) {
        $prices_array['price'][ $key ] = get_rrp_price( $price, $product_id );
    }

    return $prices_array;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices', 'filter_736700_woocommerce_variation_prices', 10, 3 );


function filter_738363_woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price( $price, $_this ) {
    if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
        $data            = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $variation_price = $data->regular_price;
        $product_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $variation_rrp_price = get_rrp_price( $variation_price, $product_id );
        update_post_meta( $product_id, $data->name . ' - regular' , $variation_rrp_price );
        $price = $variation_rrp_price;
    }

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'filter_738363_woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 10, 2);
```

Код работает везде - и для простого товара, и для вариативного. Работает как на странице товара, так и в корзине. В поле rrp2 пишется только одна цена для любого товара.

Вот снимок корзины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цена обоих товаров умножена на 10 ($kurs2).

Comment: огромная благодарность, вы просто мастер своего дела

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил в ответ еще один хук, чтобы на странице вариативного товара было правильное отображение: http://test.kagg.eu/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B/quia-qui-atque-quia-magnam/?attribute_pa_color=red

Comment: аааа черт, обнаружилась маленькая загвостка в вариативном товаре, теперь на него не назначается скидка("распродажа") если цена записана в **sale_price**, но на фронте сайта у всех вариативных цена подчеркивается как скидочная (в независимости от того заполнено поле **sale_price** или нет), пытался химичить, но подумал что лучше спросить у вас

Comment: дело в переопределении цены в **$prices_array**, но в чем именно не понял, можно ли туда как то прикрутить **onsale**?

Comment: попробую посмотреть попозже

Comment: может есть какой то хук для onsale?

Comment: Я добавил еще один хук `woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price` - он работает для обычной цены товара. Код похожий на `woocommerce_product_variation_get_price`, но я не стал сводить два хука в один, чтобы не усложнять.

Comment: Вот пример на сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B/quia-qui-atque-quia-magnam/

Comment: скидка по прежнему не назначается ни в магазине, ни в карточке товара, цены выделены жирным и подчеркнуты,при том что **sale_price** не заполнен, ранее было так: при заполнении **sale_price**, на товар назначалась **"распродажа"**, дело касается только вариативного товара, с простым все прошло как по маслу

Comment: ну у меня-то на странице вы видите, что все работает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68148/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-user271244).