# Как записать значение в произвольное поле в зависимости от значения атрибута?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вопрос заключается в записи значения в произвольное поле по заданному признаку.
В качестве признака выступает **наличие атрибута с определенным значением**.
Пробовал так (для вариативного товара), но толку нет:

```
function woocommerce_product( $price, $_this) {
    if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
        $data = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $parent_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $attribute_name  = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), ‘pa_razmer’);
        $n = 6;
        if ( $attribute_value == '30m') {
            update_post_meta($product_id, 'custom_field', $n);

        }
    }
    return;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'woocommerce_product', 10, 2);
```

Где **'custom_field'** - название произвольного поля.

**UPDATE**

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_variation_get_p( $price, $_this) {
    if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
       // $data            = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $parent_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $product_id      = 596;
        $attribute_name  = get_the_terms( $product>id, 'pa_razmer');
        $n = 6;
    foreach ( $attribute_name as $value ) {
                   //echo $value->slug;
        if ( $product_id === $parent_id ) {
            if ( $value->slug == '30m' ) {
                update_post_meta($product_id, 'custom_field', $n);


            }
        }
    }
}
    return;

}
```

Comment: У вас $attribute_value не определена

Comment: да, действительно, а как записать в нее список значений? или список значений уже хранится **$attribute_name**?

Comment: а почему не взять и не посмотреть, что там в $attribute_name?

Comment: посмотрел, расстроился - bool(false), для get_the_terms() не передаются аргументы

Comment: Я же вам показывал в своем ответе, как работать с атрибутами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735241/220220

Comment: да именно вашим кодом и руководствуюсь, но видимо не так как надо, записал  в $attribute_name все что можно касающееся атрибута 'pa_razmer', но видать у меня условие совершенно не верно?

Comment: ладно пойду пробовать тщательней, спасибо

Comment: перепробовал так и сяк, обновил ответ тем до чего дошел, нужна помощь! или скажите направление пожалуйста куда копать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67959/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-user271244).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было добавить всего одну строчку в код предыдущего моего ответа:

```
function filter_738363_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price( $price, $_this) {
    if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
        $data            = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $variation_price = $data->price;
        $product_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $variation_rrp_price = get_rrp_price( $variation_price, $product_id );
        update_post_meta( $product_id, $data->name, $variation_rrp_price );
        $price = $variation_rrp_price;
    }

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'filter_738363_woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 10, 2);
```

Так теперь выглядят произвольные поля товара под названием "Вариативный товар":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подчеркнуты поля, имеющие отношение к вопросу.